# git with Beyond Compare (4) on WSL2 Windows 11 not opening the repo version

Tags: git, wsl-2, beyondcompare

Trying to get git and Beyond Compare to place nicely together on WSL.  Here is the output from `git config --list`:

```
diff.tool=bc3
difftool.prompt=false
difftool.bc3.path=/mnt/c/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe
merge.tool=bc3
mergetool.prompt=false
mergetool.bc3.trustexitcode=true
mergetool.bc3.path=/mnt/c/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe
```

Here is my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "bc3"]
    path = /mnt/c/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
[mergetool "bc3"]
    trustExitCode = true
    path = /mnt/c/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe
```

my `git --version is`:

```
git version 2.25.1
```

When I try `git difftool file_in_git_repo`
Beyond Compare opens with the current version in the left pane, but nothing in the right pane (I have confirmed the file exists in the git repo.)

`.git/config` has no entries referencing diff or merge

Any suggestions would be most welcome

========================================================================

Similar to VonC's suggestion, I was able to get it working with this in my .gitconfig file (disclaimer - I have not used the mergetool with this new method):

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = '/mnt/c/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe'   \"$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)\"
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
[mergetool "bc3"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = '/mnt/c/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe'   \"$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)\"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check if [this configuration](https://forum.scootersoftware.com/forum/beyond-compare-4-discussion/version-control-aa/14411-new-updates-in-windows-wsl?p=82512#post82512) might work in your case:

> I managed to get it working using the built-in wslpath command which comes with new WSL versions!
>
> My git config on WSL linux side:
>
> ```
> difftool.bc3.cmd=BComp.exe "$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)" "$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)"
> mergetool.bc3.cmd=BComp.exe "$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)" "$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)" "$(wslpath -aw $BASE)" "$(wslpath -aw $MERGED)"
> ```
>
> `BComp.exe` is in my `$PATH`.
> I'm using WSL2 on Windows version 2004 (build 19041), and this works both inside the WSL filesystem and also for the mounted Windows filesystem.
>
> The new `wslpath -aw` converts the Linux paths like this:
>
> ```
> $ wslpath -aw /home/
> \\wsl$\Debian\home
> ```
>
> And Windows paths like this:
>
> ```
> $ wslpath -aw /mnt/c/Users/
> C:\Users
> ```
>
> This makes them both work perfectly with the Windows version of BC when launched from Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Using the accepted answer here and [this](https://sep.com/blog/20170607wsl-git-and-beyond-compare/) article as references I was able to arrive at a working solution for *Windows 11 + WSL2 + Ubuntu* with *Beyond Compare 4*.

From a WSL prompt I edit the Git global config like this:

```
git config --global --edit
```

I then make sure the config has lines that look like this:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc
    guitool = bc
[difftool "bc"]
    path = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Beyond\\ Compare\\ 4/bcomp.exe
    cmd = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Beyond\\ Compare\\ 4/bcomp.exe "$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)" "$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)"
    trustExitCode = true
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[merge]
    tool = bc
    guitool = bc
[mergetool "bc"]
    path = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Beyond\\ Compare\\ 4/bcomp.exe
    cmd = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Beyond\\ Compare\\ 4/bcomp.exe "$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)" "$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)" "$(wslpath -aw $BASE)" "$(wslpath -aw $MERGED)"
    trustExitCode = true
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
```

Adjust flags such as "prompt" to your taste.

Answer (score 1):

VonC's solution got me most of the way there, but didn't seem to work with dir-diff i.e. `git difftool -d`. For that to work I needed to add the following to the .gitconfig on the WSL2 side.

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
```

Alternately you can run `git difftool -d --no-symlinks`